# Варианты вёрстки нестандартного примера

Tags: css, вёрстка

Каким образом можно реализовать в вёрстке что-то подобное?

[image: пример]

Интересует именно каким образом лучше всего сделать эту рамку. В голове вариант, что просто вставить как бекграунд, но тогда как это будет выглядеть в адаптивной вёрстке?

Comment: убрать рамку. имхо будет лучше ) но с дизайнером не поспоришь...

Comment: вот набросал приблизительный вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/v7wm9q9y/

Answer (score 5):

Рискну предложить:

1. Картинка 1:Горы, бэк.
2. Картинка 2:Человек,над горами
3. нижняя и по сторонам рамка - border у div с z-index больше чем человек
4. верхняя - сверху внутри предыдущего (чтоб рамка не ползла) другой див с z-index меньше чем человек.

Comment: этот ответ универсальней. просто сделать парочку вложенных div для нижней и остальных границ, а далее по инструкции Darth-а

Answer (score 4):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: rgb(98, 125, 77);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, rgba(98, 125, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 59, 8, 1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, rgba(98, 125, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 59, 8, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, rgba(98, 125, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 59, 8, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(98, 125, 77, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 59, 8, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#627d4d', endColorstr='#1f3b08', GradientType=1);
}
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 55px 15px;
}
.b-inner {
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 25px 180px 25px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.b-inner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
.b-inner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
.pict-man {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="b-inner">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>Интересует именно каким образом лучше всего сделать эту рамку. В голове вариант, что просто вставить как бекграунд, но тогда как это будет выглядеть в адаптивной вёрстке?</p>
      <div class="pict-man">man</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

вариант:

- картинка 1 - горы
- картинка 2 - человек
- рамка - это div с раскрашенной границей

картинки можно объединить в спрайт

нет ничего страшного в том, что у Вас будет две (один спрайт) картинки вместо одной

Comment: Каким образом рамка за головой человека скроется? верстка адаптивная же

Comment: разумеется на картинке с человеком должна быть белая линия границы. при смешении человека по гирозонтале линия будет рамки будет продолжать совпадать с линией границы div

Comment: правильно я понимаю, что на рисунке с человеком будет нарисована линия?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: А если завтра захотят изменить цвет рамки? На мой взгляд не самый лучший способ. В любом случаи, спасибо за конструктивный диалог)

Comment: соглашусь, решение Darth-а подходит лучше