# Альтернативная анимация со свойством width

Tags: javascript, css

Имеется [такая](https://jsfiddle.net/udmqzkm9/) кнопка поиска.
По умолчанию ширина увеличивается вправо.
Каким образом можно сделать что-бы ширина увеличивалась в противоположную сторону(влево)?
Js:

```
var getSearch = document.getElementById('search');
var setSearchHolder = document.getElementById('searchHolder');
getSearch.onmouseover = function(){
    getSearch.style.width = "220px";
    setSearchHolder.style.opacity = "1";
    setSearchHolder.style.width = "150px";
    getSearch.style.opacity = "1";
}
getSearch.onmouseout = function(){
    getSearch.style.width = "38px";
    setSearchHolder.style.opacity = "0";
    setSearchHolder.style.width = "0px";
    getSearch.style.opacity = "0.6";
}
```

Comment: решение обязательно должно быть на `js`?

Comment: Не обязательно на js.

Comment: прижать кнопку вправо https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/mhgL35nu/

Comment: @soledar а почему вы не пишете ответы? В [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486014/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/486059#486059) вы тоже в комментарий написали решение, достойное быть ответом.

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо прижать ваш блок с поиском вправо

1. Используем `float: right;`
2. Используем `text-align: right` для `parent` и `display: inline-block` для `child`

Вариант на css

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;  
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: right;
}

.b-search{
  width: 0;  
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #00f;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-search:hover{
  width: 150px;
}
.b-search input[type="search"]{
  width: 100%;    
  border: none;
  height: 20px;
}
.b-search [type="submit"]{
  border: none;
  position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="b-search">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button type="submit"></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Ваш вариант(здесь использует float: right)

```js
var getSearch = document.getElementById('search');
var setSearchHolder = document.getElementById('searchHolder');

getSearch.onmouseover = function() {
  getSearch.style.width = "220px";
  setSearchHolder.style.opacity = "1";
  setSearchHolder.style.width = "150px";
  getSearch.style.opacity = "1";
}
getSearch.onmouseout = function() {
  getSearch.style.width = "38px";
  setSearchHolder.style.opacity = "0";
  setSearchHolder.style.width = "0px";
  getSearch.style.opacity = "0.6";

}
```

```css
#search {
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: right;
  width: 38px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-left: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
#searchHolder {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
#searchHolder input {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #888;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#searchLink img {
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchPosition">
  <div id="search">
    <div id="searchHolder">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" id="inputText">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="searchLink">
      <img src="img/search-icon.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
```