# Как прервать border?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно как бы за головой продолжить бордед, где красная стрелка. Каким способом можно это сделать?

Сейчас по бокам и снизу бордер, а сверху линейный-градиент

```
background-image: linear-gradient(white 1%, transparent 1%, transparent 100%, white 50%);
background-size: 693px 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: :before or :after

Comment: как вариант - добавить два псевдоелемента слева и справа от картинки на уровне головы. но очень тяжело будет состыковать. либо сделать через legend - этот элемент разрывает верхний бордер для своего текста.

Comment: у меня дежавю или такой вопрос пару месяцев назад уже был?

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать !

Comment: @Invision http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486014/185624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай контейнеру где фотка с головой
z-index: 1;

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос задан 4 года назад))